# Visualization of 1D spin chain wave fuction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spin-models

What are the known methods for visualizing quantum states of one-dimensional spin chains? They can be based either on their wave functions or density matrices.

My particular interest is in plotting eigenstates of 1D spin chains (e.g. Heisenberg model) in a way in which correlations between particles are related to the self-similarity of the image.

**As a side note**, I found a [Wikipedia Commons image with its description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Ising-tartan.png) on the topic (a thumbnail below). However, it is not supported neither by a peer reviewed publication nor by a decent preprint. The [only text related](http://linas.org/math/lattice.pdf) is extremely drafty.

However, I'm the most interested in published results, and even more when they relate properties of the image to the properties of the state.

[image]

Comment: Eventually, I co-wrote a paper on it: [Qubism: self-similar visualization of many-body wavefunctions](http://arxiv.org/abs/1112.3560).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to be answering your own question. Obviously there is far too much information to represent in a reasonably sized 2d or 3d plot, so no matter what you do, you will be losing something. If you want a plot that shows correlations between particles, you can do just that: For a spinchain of $N$ sites, create a $N\times N$ image, where the value of the pixel at each point $(i,j)$ is given by the expectation value of the operator $\sigma^A_i \sigma^B_j$, where $\sigma^{A/B}_{i/j} \in \{\sigma_X, \sigma_Y, \sigma_Z\}$. This gives you 9 possible plots.

It seems likely that you may only care about the case where $\sigma^A = \sigma^B$, in which case there are only 3 plots, and you could take the expectation values for $XX$, $YY$ and $ZZ$ as the R, G and B values for a colour plot.

This kind of thing produces things very similar to the type of plot you have in your question.

Comment: I edited my question not to seem that I am answering myself. I know quite a few methods how to make a plot out of a spin chain wave function. However, I'm searching for references, especially with detailed analysis of the graphical representations.

Comment: @PiotrMigdal: It seems to me that you want references to papers that specifically discuss how to draw such plots, but I doubt these really exist. We have excellent measures of correlation (i.e. concurrence, etc) between sites, but how you plot them is up to you. For two-site correlations, a 2D image or surface plot in 3D of the value of the correlation (for whatever metric you choose) is the natural choice.

Answer (score 6):

The image you have posted looks like a [recurrence plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_plot) to me.  It is primarily used to visualize correlation information in time-series data, but it can be used with any discrete set.  A particularly good source of information is this [website](http://www.recurrence-plot.tk/).

Comment: @rollyer: Actually, for translation-invariant states recurrence plot is a function only of the difference of the position, i.e. $r(x,x') = f(x-x')$ (tough for other applications it is a nice tool).

Comment: @PiotrMigdal, point. But, I think you could use it for the cross-correlation between sites.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't really an answer on its own, more an addendum to Joe's...

You are not, I think, going to find a "detailed analysis" of how correlation function have been plotted in most papers. Your best bet is to look at various examples - Nature and Science papers will be most helpful for this, as they are heavy on the graphical representation and have space for lots of supplementary material.

A good example of the sorts of plots Joe talked about, in sets that make it easy to see the transitions, is http://www.nature.com/nphys/journal/v7/n5/fig_tab/nphys1919_F6.html